# trying to find the id from the data attribute and set it up

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have DataTables where there is no ID i am getting from my tables

Following this:

https://jsfiddle.net/44f0pcx2/3/

I tried to find the id from this which is my structure

```
rowId: function(a) {
                console.log(a);
                console.log($(this).find('a.add').data('id'));
                return 'id_' + $(this).find('.add').data('id');
            }
```

the results i am getting for every rw is like this:

```
{phonenumber: "45454545", name: "bill", action: "<a href="javascript:;" class="add" data-id="13">Add</a>", …}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do that . It works on the snippet ..But I didn't know it will work on a big scale or not .. You can try it

- To get the html string you can use `a.action`

```js
var a = {phonenumber: "45454545", name: "bill", action: "<a href='javascript:;' class='add' data-id='13'>Add</a>"};

var GetId = $('<div/>').append(a.action).find('.add').data('id'); // create a div and append the `<a>` to it and get the attribute
console.log(GetId);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```